# Is there code to get rid of the repository details in GitHub?

Tags: github

GitHub just now displayed a right hand margin with the title "About".

It then shows various categories and a description.

Was there something in my code that started this?

How to get rid of this?

I don't recall ever seeing before. It's the default? New?

A way to programmatically adjust?

Comment: They just *moved* that content, on the page; it already existed. If you want to configure it, click the cog.

Comment: You are mistaken, because my question was addressing its appearance in the right hand margin. Now it turns out that their blog says they did in fact change the appearance of the page as of June 23, 2020. see here https://github.blog/changelog/2020-06-23-design-updates-to-repositories-and-github-ui/

Comment: Mistaken? That's what I said: it moved on the page, they moved it to the sidebar. The elements you mention, category tags and a description, already existed.

Comment: But my question wasn't about whether that content existed before. Plus I did click the cog of course, but it doesn't let you reclaim the right margin.

Answer (score -1):

New info from Aug 4, 2020 from Github support:

"Aug 4, 2020, 1:21 PM UTC"

"Sorry for not getting back to you as quickly as we'd like! Please accept my apologies.
I'm afraid there's no way to minimize or remove the "About" section built into GitHub, sorry!
I know that some of our users, who feel as you do, have attempted to come up with some browser extensions that restore the old UI.
They are mentioned in this thread of the Community Forum:"

https://github.community/t/how-to-opt-out-of-the-new-ui/119416/194

Previous answer:

It turns out the answer to this question is that yes, github did in fact change the layout of the repository page. In doing so, they took away valuable real estate and made their web site less useful in some ways. My question is directed at the new feature listed as:

- More content surfaced via the repository sidebar

https://github.blog/changelog/2020-06-23-design-updates-to-repositories-and-github-ui/

If there is a way to return to github classic, I'd like to know.

Comment: This is making stackoverflow less useful, because a valid question is downvoted. All I wanted to know if whether I'd done something with my code or the tool to create a problem that didn't exist before. No, it turns out, nothing in my remote push changed the appearance. There is no git command or github api call that can change it back.

Why this is a sin to ask, I don't know.